# How to submit a jar using python script in apache livy?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have made a jar in which my main code is (written in java spark). 
I also have some external jars needed to run my main code ( main jar)
How can I submit and execute my jar  using python script in Livy ?
(using spark-submit)

I just need a syntax of how to do spark-submit where my python script should export my main jar ( i am using 'request' in python for livy )

**update**

Getting some error in batch submit in livy .

*spark logic* :
[spark logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAq9Q.png)

*livy code*
[livy code in which above file is accessed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwMYl.png)

*spark-submit (terminal)*
[spark-submit command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD9lm.png)

*livy log*

[livy log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYupQ.png)

Everything working fine when i submit code using `/statements` but now i am taking my code through a file using `/batches` , my SparkContext isnt working.
Also using `response = request.get()` while using `/statements` i was able to get output in my `response.json()` but now using `/batches` (considering i am externally initializing SparkContext) i am not able to get output in my json though it is showing in livy log.

Comment: Please add in more details on what you have done with your code. add in screenshot if possible The question is a little vague to answer.

Comment: what i wrote in my java spark code is just some methods to perform some operations but i think its not that much relevant to solve my doubt. , any other information i should add ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example from my recent project.The jars are on a S3 bucket.
You can edit the code to use jars from a file location on your cluster all nodes
Please refer to the following snippet, 
master_dns is the dns address of the livy master.

```
import json, requests
def spark_submit(master_dns):
        host = 'http://' + master_dns + ':8998'
        data = {"conf": {"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"},
                'file': "s3://<your driver jar>",
                "jars": ["s3://<dependency>.jar"]
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        print("Calling request........")
        response = requests.post(host + '/batches', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
        print(response.json())
        return response.headers
```

Comment: hey..thank you. It worked. Actually i was trying with sample  pyspark file first. I  am getting output in log file but i am not able to fetch it. I  am doing " r = request.get(host + '/batches/{id}' , headers = headers ) ... Please help

Comment: also, while submitting in '/batches' , i  am getting error "sc" is not defined , though i have later created sparkcontext in my file but why livy isnt creating it by default ? It was perfectly working when i was using direct code but via file ( batch) its not working.

Comment: You do not need any spark context or sc for a livy client. Please share your code and error received

Comment: please checkout the edited question, i have attatched everything done so far.

Comment: Please do check

Comment: 1. You need to create a sc in your spark job , since livy is just an interface to access your cluster via rest API
2. Please share the output of your response object (r).
Finally there are two ways to us livy a) RestAPI , what i have suggested b. Programatic API , which does not require a sc.
Please refer to the documentation.

Comment: I am easily able to verify the status using
statement_status = ''
host = 'http://' + master_dns + ':8998'
session_url = host + response_headers['location'].split('/statements', 1)[0]
statement_url = host + response_headers['location']
statement_response = requests.get(statement_url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
statement_status = statement_response.json()['state']

Comment: Can you help me with the first part of my question where I am asking about sharing the session which I am created in 1st request which need to be accessed in 2nd request so that i can directly use processed data frame ..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57404189/apache-livy-how-to-share-the-same-spark-session

Comment: Please check my response, Please upvote the answers if it solves your question

Comment: Thanks I had the same issue. Can you please let me know if Hadoop is prerequsite for Livy to work or Spark standalone is sufficient? @NehaJirafe

Comment: @user007 No Livy does not depend on Hadoop

Comment: Thanks @NehaJirafe. I was able to run livy server on terminal but I am not able to get its status change to 'running': It starts from 'starting' and then 'waiting' but not to 'running'. Could it be an issue with the installation? I did not see any error thrown during installation though.