# Apache Livy : How to share the same spark session?

Tags: apache-spark

considering batch mode of livy , 
I have submitted one file/jar in which my spark logic is written.
How can I share a spark session created by one `POST/batches` with say `{'id':1}` with another `POST/batches` with `{'id':2}` ? 
Reason for doing so is , the transformations I have applied and stored in a dataframe I need to use that in different task by sharing same session ( I can write and then read the result but I want to remove that overhead )

**issue:**

Also one issue I am facing is while executing following , I am getting sc/spark not defined if I am using spatk functionality eg `sc.parallelize()` or `spark.read.csv()` in my code

```py
headers = {" Content-type" : "application/json"}
data = {'file' : '<file/path> ' }
request.post( host+'/batches' , data= json.dumps(data), headers = headers }
```

Is there anything I am missing above because when I do this in *interactive* mode sc/spark gets initialise automatically ?

**Update**

```py
data = {'kind':'pyspark'}
r = requests.post(host + '/sessions', data=json.dumps(data),headers=headers)



data = {'code':'rdd1 = sc.parallelize([1,2,3])'}

rqm = requests.post(host + '/sessions/0/statements', data=json.dumps(data),headers=headers)

pprint.pprint(rqm.json())

rsm = r = requests.get(host + '/sessions/0/statements')

pprint.pprint(rsm.json())




data = {'code':'print(rdd1.collect())'}

rqs = requests.post(host + '/sessions/0/statements', data=json.dumps(data),headers=headers)

pprint.pprint(rqs.json())

rss = requests.get(host + '/sessions/0/statements')

pprint.pprint(rss.json())
```

This way I have shared `sessions` and access `rdd` in interactive mode.
How can I do the same in `batch` mode ?

please provide a simple sample code because I am new to livy and its tough for me to understand complex code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Livy Client API for this purpose. If you are using Apache Livy the below python API can help you.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/tree/master/python-api

Else you have to main the LIVY Session and use the same session to submit the spark JOBS.

Livy Python Client example

//execute a job in Livy Server 
1. JOBName
2. data

```
def run_job(test,input_data):
result = None
try:
    global client
    if client is None:
        client = setup_livy_client()

    logger.info('submitting job')
    start_time = time.time()
    result_future = client.submit(test(input_data))
    result = result_future.result(timeout=JOB_RESULT_TIMEOUT)
    end_time = time.time()
    logger.info('algorithm took %d secs'%(end_time - start_time))
except TimeoutError:
    logger.error('TimeoutError in job processing: ', exc_info=True)
    client = None
except Exception:
    logger.error('Error in job processing: ',exc_info=True)
return result

def get_client():
    logger.info("Obtaining Livy server {} connection".format(LIVY_SERVER_URL))
    try:
        client = HttpClient(LIVY_SERVER_URL, load_defaults=True, conf_dict=livy_config)
        return client
    except e:
        logger.info("Unsuccesful in obtaining livy-connection")
        return None
```

//to upload the files in hdfs

```
def upload_all_jobs(client):
    upload_start_time = time.time()
    logger.info('uploading file to all worker nodes %s' % ("job_path"))
    print("uploading file %s"%("job_path"))
    client.add_pyfile("job_path").result(FILE_UPLOAD_TIMEOUT)
    print("file uploaded")
    upload_end_time = time.time()
    logger.info('file uploaded in %d secs' % (upload_end_time-upload_start_time))

def setup_livy_client():

    logger.info("######## getting client connection ")
    global client
    client = get_client()
    logger.info("######## obtained client connection")
    upload_all_jobs(client)

    return client
```

//test Livy JOB which needs to be executed

```
def test(input_data):
    def simple_spark_job(context):
        elements = input_data.get('data',[])
        return context.sc.parallelize(elements, 2).count()
    return simple_spark_job
```

Comment: About your later part , _"Else you have to main the LIVY Session and use the same session to submit the spark JOBS."_ , suppose i have created a SparkSession as _spark_ so how to pass that session to another job using `request.post()` ? please give me the syntax in `request.post()` as I am using python and I am not able to get how to share the same session. Please help as I am searching it for long time.

Comment: Please help me with that.

Comment: two questions 
1. why you are using batch mode if you want to share the spark session.
2. what exceptions are you getting the submitting the batch request

Comment: Livy server version?

Comment: 1. Because I have a jar in which my main code is written. Using `spark-submit` we are currently executing those jars. This is for 1 task , such multiple tasks I need to execute which means I am doing multiple `spark-submit` as well and all this is managed using airflow in a python script ( I have no idea about airflow) , but instead of using multiple spark sessions , I need a global spark session which will be used by all those `spark-submit` tasks so that I can share processed dataframes.

Comment: 2. I am not getting any exceptions as such but as I have mentioned in point 1 , I am not able to share my dataframes ( as I am not able to share sessions ). So what I need is , using REST in python script , I will pass my jar in `POST/batches` and will share my dataframes between tham.  So is there **anyway** can I do this thing ? Please share anything if you have.

Comment: `Apache Livy 0.6.0-incubating`

Comment: please refer https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/python-api/src/test/python/livy-tests/client_test.py

Comment: 1 . Hey can u tell me a bit what that code is all about ? I mean what it is doing ? So that I can use it. 2. What need to install to do `from livy.client import HttpClient` coz i got error last time `HttpClient` not defined , may be because import failure.

Answer (score 1):

Please use Programatic API which has its own spark context [https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/programmatic-api.html][1]

You need create a LivyClient instance and upload your application code to the Spark context and submit.

I dont see a python API for programatic livy.So you may have to use Scala or Java

Comment: Actually , project is nearly finished and we are writing the result into hdfs and again reading it as an input , which is huge overhead. So i have been assigned to solve this. I thought i can share the session and reuse that dataframe instead of writing and reading it again. So I thought of using livy for that. Airflow creates a python script so I thought of using REST in it thats why I cant switch to Scala/Java . Do you have any other alternative or idea to do so. Please help.

Comment: You may want to checkout https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Comment: I read about spark-jobserver but can I use my **python** airflow code (which submits my spark jobs)  to share sessions ?

Comment: Please share your airflow code. If you are using a PythonOperator, you can try passing the "sc" as an argument

Comment: Actually I am not having airflow code right now.  Can you check the updated part of the question and try to resolve my query. I am new to livy and i am not able to understand some parameters, couldnt find proper documentation and the official doc I couldnt find much helpful . Please elaborate in simple terms.